# How to insert covariates in logistic regression?

Tags: spss

I am running a binary logistic regression in SPSS and have the following setup:

- One dichotomous DV
- Two dichotomous IVs
- Two covariates that were measured on 7 point Likert scales

When inserting the covariates into the regression model, SPSS asks you to define the reference category for categorical variables. Must I also do this for the two covariates?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to define reference category for IV (because they are dichotomous) and covariates (because they are ordinal). ATM, I don't remember SPSS dialogue box, but you can simply add the covariates as  continuous predictors (like any other IV).